# How to Exclude item from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter or Firebase Reference Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm working on Activity to show all the others app users except my user and i'm using Java android with Firebase  .

But i cant find anyway to exclude item from DatabaseReference or from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter .

My Activity look like this

[image]

My Database look like this :

[image]

My code inside this Activity looks like below :

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     myRef = database.getReference().child("users");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users,RecyclerViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, RecyclerViewHolder>(Users.class , R.layout.users_single_layout ,RecyclerViewHolder.class,myRef  ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
                 viewHolder.setDisolayName(model.getDisplay_name());
                viewHolder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
                viewHolder.setImage(model.getImager_thumb(), getContext());
                frinds_relative.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                final  String users_id = getRef(position).getKey();
                viewHolder.mview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent target = new Intent(getActivity() , user_profile.class);
                        target.putExtra("profile_id" , users_id) ;
                        startActivity(target);
                    }
                });


        }
    };
    users_recycler.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

I will be thankful if you have the solution .

Comment: exclude item? .. like what item?

Comment: i mean to hide the item from the list something like add condition not equal

Comment: AFAIK, `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` doesn't provide such function. You have to create Custom adapter according to your needs.

Comment: Ah thank you but i think its so hectic !!

Answer (score 2):

I faced something similar once and how i did it was..

First thing is to give the parent layout and id in the users_single_layout xml file;
Reference the parent layout in the viewholder;
Then hide all the content of file by :

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

When That is done, You set and if statement in your FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:
Check the Code Below:

```
users_recycler = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users,RecyclerViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, RecyclerViewHolder>(Users.class , R.layout.users_single_layout ,RecyclerViewHolder.class,myRef  ) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {

            if (adapter.getRef(position).getKey.equals(currentUid){

                 viewholder.thelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

             } else {

                 viewHolder.setDisolayName(model.getDisplay_name());
            viewHolder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
            viewHolder.setImage(model.getImager_thumb(), getContext());
            frinds_relative.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            final  String users_id = getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.mview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent target = new Intent(getActivity() , user_profile.class);
                    target.putExtra("profile_id" , users_id) ;
                    startActivity(target);
                }
            });

             }


    }
};
users_recycler.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The FirebaseUI `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is a direct representation of the data in the underlying `Query` or exists at a location in a Firebase database. To exclude an item from an adapter, you have to exclude it first from the Firebase location or ensure it doesn't match that particular query anymore.

To achieve this, you can use the following line of code:

```
yourAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();
```

Comment: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Dosen't has remove() function

Comment: yourAdapter.getRef(position) returns a `DatabaseReference` object which has `removeValue()` method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Its removing the value not only from adapter but from the database too , thank you for helping but its not what i want